# GetMethod in Interface as field of class c#?

Tags: c#, interface

This is program for calculator. Examine I have:

```
public Interface IFunction{
    string Name {get; }
    double Eval();
}
```

And

```
public class subtract:IFunction{
    private double x,y;
    public double Eval(){
     return x - y;
     }
    public string Name{
        get { return "subtract";}
    }
}

public class add:IFunction{
    private double x, y;
    public double Eval(){
     return x + y;
     }
    public string Name{
        get { return "add";}
    }
}
```

I have to write class, who has string field operation. For the name of that string field I must use `Name{ get; }` from `IFunction`, which can be `"add"` or `"subtract".` If is "subtract", implement subtract operation, calling `Eval()` method from `subtract` class, and etc; How to make polymorphic calling of this method in class `Calculator`? Must `Calculator` class implement Interface?

```
 public class Calculator{
    private double leftOperand, rightOperand;
    private string operation;
    public double Calculate(){
    /*here must call Eval() from subtract or add, depending    on `operation` */
    }
}
```

Comment: `operation` should be `IFunction`. `subtract` and `add` both need a way to give them x and y (either constructor or arguments to Eval)

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Calculator` contain a list of the `IFunction`:

```
private IList<IFunction> functions;
```

Then iterate that list when `Calculate` is called:

```
IFunction function = functions.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == operation);
```

Then if it is null just throw an exception or give a default value back.

Also as mentioned by @Rob in the comments the `IFunction`s need a way to assign the `x` and `y` values this can be by a property:

```
public double X { get; set; }
```

or modifying the interface so the `Eval` method accepts them as arguments:

```
double Eval(double x, double y);
```

So putting this together I would do the following in `Calculate`

```
IFunction function = functions.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == operation);
if (function == null)
{
    //Or return some default value
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("operation", "Unable to find the operation in the list of available ones");
}

return Eval(leftOperand, rightOperand);
```